# Docker + NodeJs in Windows server

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, npm, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize a nodeJS service on a windows 2019 server host machine.
Here is how my dockerFile looks like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 as installer

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/node-v16.20.1-win-x64.zip"; Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; Rename-Item "C:\\node-v16.20.1-win-x64" c:\nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

WORKDIR C:/nodejs
COPY --from=installer C:/nodejs/ .

# Set the PATH environment variable to include C:\nodejs
ENV PATH="C:\nodejs"

# Code for the app
WORKDIR C:/app/

COPY package*.json ./

USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN npm install



# Bundle app source
COPY . .

RUN npm run build
ENV ENV="dev"

EXPOSE 8004

# Two options to run the service

# option 1 - Does not work
# CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:apiService" ]

# option 2 - working, I have to navigate to the build folder where my api.js is present and do 'node api.js'(which is also done by 'npm run start:apiService')
# WORKDIR C:/app/build/src/apiService/
# ENTRYPOINT ["node", "api.js"]
```

Its a pretty plain implementation.

- I am using windows base image.
- installing node in the image and doing npm install.
- did npm run build to build my code.
- Exposed ports and setup env variable needed to run.
- To run the node service i need to run `npm run start:apiService`

Not able to understand why is option 1 not working in windows host when i try to up the container?
I get below error while running `docker run -it b04bf0cec945 -p 8004:8004`

Error in windows:
`docker: Error response from daemon: container fe680aa17900d1c8c899e20b90413b5bf24929345cec6487751ce7a175140b16 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2).`

while using ENTRYPOINT after navigating to build folder works!!!

here is how my package.json script section is mapped to my npm run cmd:-

`"start:apiService": "node build/src/apiService/api.js"`